# Generics and protocol conformance in Swift functions

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I just read [Brent Simmon's post on a problem he is having with Swift](http://inessential.com/2015/06/21/swift_protocols_question) and I thought I had the answer: generic protocol conformance.

The problem he's having is that he has a protocol, `Value`, that conforms to `Equatable`. He has another protocol, `Smashable`, that requires the function `valueBySmashingOtherValue`. He has a struct, `Bar`, that does in fact conform to `Smashable` and `Value`.

In a subsequent function that takes a generic type `T`, a `Bar` is returned. The Swift type system complains that `'Bar' is not convertible to 'T'`.

Here's what I thought would work:

```
protocol Value: Equatable { }

protocol Smashable {
    func valueBySmashing​OtherValue​<T: Value, Smashable>(value: T) -> T
}

struct Bar: Smashable, Value {
    func valueBySmashing​OtherValue​<T: Value, Smashable>(value: T) -> T {
        return value;
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Bar, rhs: Bar) -> Bool {
    return false
}

struct Foo {
    func valueBySmashing​OtherValue​<T: Value, Smashable>(value: T) -> T {
        return Bar()
    }
}
```

Make the generic type `T` conform to `Value` and `Smashable`. `Bar` does in fact conform to these, so the type system should be fine with you returning it.

But it isn't. Why?

Comment: Because return `T` is also constrained by the type of input parameter, which may be incompatible with `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that `Bar` conforms to `Value` and `Smashable` it is not the *only* type that meets those criteria. I could create a new type (using latest Swift syntax):

```
struct NotBar: Smashable, Value {
    func valueBySmashing​OtherValue​<T:Value where T:Smashable>(value: T) -> T {
        return value;
    }
}
func ==(lhs: NotBar, rhs: NotBar) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

If I passed an instance of `NotBar` into `Foo.valueBySmashing​OtherValue`, then I would expect a `NotBar` in return. The compiler knows this so it does not allow you to return a `Bar`.